# PowerShell run Ultraedit Script

Tags: powershell, ultraedit

Is it possible to run an UltraEdit macro or script from the PowerShell? Something like following:

```
uedit64.exe c:\temp\test.txt /s,e="c:\temp\script.js"
```

I have nothing special. I just want to open the **log file** with **UltraEdit** and as soon the **log file** is opened the UltraEdit Script should be executed on that. The following code **opens** the log file **but does not execute** the script on that.

```
$ultraEdit = "C:\...\UltraEdit\uedit64.exe"
$logFile = "C:\...\res.log"
$scriptFile = "C:\...\ultraEditScript.js"

Start-Process -FilePath $ultraEdit -ArgumentList "$logFile /s=`"$scriptFile`""
```

Comment: Have a look at `Start-Process` and its [examples at the bottom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6#examples)

Comment: I already looked at the documentation but could not figure it out how to open a file with Ultraedit and run a script on that file. I need this with PowerShell "https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/run-macro-script-from-command-line.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone,
The problem was with **Select-String** that split the matched lines, therefore, the script did not perform any action due to improper file structure.

These two works great :-)

```
1. & $ultraEdit /fni $logFile /S=$scriptFile

2. Start-Process -FilePath $ultraEdit -ArgumentList "$logFile /S=$scriptFile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Powershell has a few different "call" operators.
https://ss64.com/ps/call.html

Take a look at the documentation for Start-process.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\pathtoexe\uedit64.exe" -ArgumentList "c:\temp\test.txt /s,e=`"c:\temp\script.js`""
```

Should work for you (change the path of course.

Comment: Well you will need to show me the actual code you are using for me to help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  The problem with your current example is surrounding quoting rules with arguments:

```
uedit64.exe c:\temp\test.txt '/s,e="c:\temp\script.js"'
```

This form should work.  When you use commas, [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) will interpret that as an array.  The safest way to pass arguments to an external executable is to use the stop-parser operator (`--%`) to avoid [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)'s interpretation, but note this falls back to the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) parser on Windows:

```
#requires -Version 3
uedit64.exe --% C:\Temp\test.txt /s,e="C:\Temp\script.js"
```

What the difference in parsers means is that you can't expand variables (if you wanted `$path\script.js`) in the arguments after the stop-parser, but you can still utilize environment variables using the batch syntax `%VAR%`.

As a best-practice, it's recommended to fully-qualify your path and use the call operator for clarity:

```
& C:\Temp\uedit64.exe
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them work, I already played and tried similar approaches but no success :-(

Comment: @AbdulRahmanSherzad This sounds like an issue with how your application works, then.